# Nested templates are not binding 2 way to Controller variables

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

Having a lot of trouble with the following setup (which i cant change without a major rewrite).
The overview of the issue is that when I embed a partial via ng-include from another partial which was loaded via a ui-view (from ui-router) ng-bind is not binding back to the controller scope.

Here is a simplified example...
Here is the ui router

```
.state('investments', {
        url: '/investments/:Uid',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/investments.html',
        controller: 'InvestmentsCtrl',
        parent: 'root'
      })
        .state('investments.funds', {
          url: '',
          templateUrl: 'views/investments/funds.html',
        })
```

The first partial - views/**investments.html** includes a ui-view

```
<div>
  <section class="entity-details clearfix" ui-view></section>
</div>
```

Which loads up **funds.html** which contains the following

```
<tabset class="tabbable">
<tab>
    <ng-include src="'/views/investments/_investment.html'"></ng-include>
</tab>
```

And finally **_investment.html** has an input box which is binding to a variable on the controller (InvestController)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query" ng-model="invsearch.query"/>
<button ng-click="update();">Update</button>
```

Now in the **controller** I have the following:

```
angular.module('cougarApp')
  .controller('InvestController', function ($scope, $sce, $state, $debounce) {

     $scope.invsearch = {};

     $scope.update= function () {
         console.log($scope.invsearch);
    };
```

So its pretty straight forward (despite all the nested includes).
Bottom line when i click the button which calls $scope.update() - the function is called in the controller however the value of $scope.invsearch is an empty object. Even if I put a value into my textbox??

Now the exact same code works when I dont use the initial ui-view.
ie if my first template calls an ng-include directly then everything works fine.
I am still a little new to angular and there is obviously something about nested scopes that I am missing here.

Please can someone help me out here.
Thanks

Comment: where you declare **InvestController**?

Comment: i just pasted the relevant snippet from my controller. I have updated and shown the controller declaration above

Comment: Which state does `InvestController` belong to?  In the code pasted, the parent state requires `InvestmentsCtrl`, and the child state has no controller specified.  This is key to understanding  the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the controller in your investments.html file like this.

```
<div ng-controller="InvestmentsCtrl">
  <section class="entity-details clearfix" ui-view></section>
</div>
```